# Python aggregation of multiple columns using a composite key

Tags: python

I am wondering how to aggregate multiple columns using a key. I have working code for aggregating a single column but I would like to extend it to multiple columns.

Below is some sample data. The actual summation does not make much sense, the data is for illustration of the problem.

The code below creates a key on Tm, Lg, Pos and sums up PTS.

I would like to sum up PTS and G for the same key.

I can trivially do this in pandas but would like to use Python and not pandas.

```
$ cat test-file.csv
Season,Age,Tm,Lg,Pos,G,FGA,PTS
2003-04,22,MIA,NBA,PG,61,13.1,16.2
2004-05,23,MIA,NBA,SG,77,17.1,24.1
2005-06,24,MIA,NBA,SG,75,18.8,27.2
2006-07,25,MIA,NBA,SG,51,18.9,27.4
2007-08,26,MIA,NBA,SG,51,18.4,24.6
2008-09,27,MIA,NBA,SG,79,22.0,30.2
2009-10,28,MIA,NBA,SG,77,19.6,26.6
2010-11,29,MIA,NBA,SG,76,18.2,25.5
2011-12,30,MIA,NBA,SG,49,17.1,22.1
2012-13,31,MIA,NBA,SG,69,15.8,21.2
2013-14,32,MIA,NBA,SG,54,14.1,19.0
2014-15,33,MIA,NBA,SG,62,17.5,21.5
2015-16,34,MIA,NBA,SG,74,16.0,19.0
2016-17,35,CHI,NBA,SG,60,15.9,18.3
2017-18,36,CLE,NBA,SG,46,9.5,11.2
2017-18,36,MIA,NBA,SG,21,11.8,12.0
2018-19,37,MIA,NBA,SG,72,13.3,15.0


import csv
import re
from collections import namedtuple

totals = {}

with open ('/home/test-file.csv', 'r') as input_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)

    record = namedtuple('record', header)

    for rec in (record._make(row) for row in reader):
        totals[rec.Tm, rec.Lg, rec.Pos] = \
            (totals.get((rec.Tm, rec.Lg, rec.Pos), 0.0) + \
            float(rec.PTS))
    for key, value in sorted(totals.items()):
        row = list(key) + [value]
        print(row)

['CHI', 'NBA', 'SG', 18.3]
['CLE', 'NBA', 'SG', 11.2]
['MIA', 'NBA', 'PG', 16.2]
['MIA', 'NBA', 'SG', 315.4]
```

I am looking for output like below, i.e., two aggregate columns.

```
['CHI', 'NBA', 'SG', 60, 18.3]
['CLE', 'NBA', 'SG', 46, 11.2]
['MIA', 'NBA', 'PG', 61, 16.2]
['MIA', 'NBA', 'SG', 887, 315.4]
```

Edit: Typo, "summation does" to "summation does not".

Comment: You could sort, and use itertools groupby. Can you provide the inputs without the reading csv stuff ?

Comment: You can do it easily using [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/) using a `groupby` along with your aggregation.

Comment: @Abitbol, OP knows "I can do trivially do this in pandas but would like to use Python and not pandas. "

Comment: Woops my bad sorry...

Comment: I'm trying to think of a reason why you wouldn't use pandas. It's significantly more readable and easier to implement.

Comment: @BlueSheepToken, I will take a look at itertools but the data would be coming from files.

Comment: @AnthonyR for example if you want to use such function in the cloud, e.g. in AWS lambda. Or have a low memory footprint. Or don't want to install hundreds of dependcies that come along with pandas. etc etc

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, that makes sense ! @Drey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BlueSheepToken suggested, group by from itertools is your friend. Other python native and performant solutions are implemented in either `funcy` or `toolz` packages. Here a solution with `toolz`

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
import toolz
import toolz.curried

def stream_file(fp):
    with open(fp) as file:
        for line in csv.DictReader(file):
            res = dict(line)
            res['G'] = float(res['G'])
            res['PTS'] = float(res['PTS'])
            yield res

# groups from stream
groups = toolz.groupby(['Tm', 'Lg', 'Pos'], stream_file('test_file.csv'))

# aggregation functions: get some value from list, then sum it up
pts_counter = toolz.compose_left(toolz.curried.map(itemgetter('PTS')), sum)
g_counter = toolz.compose_left(toolz.curried.map(itemgetter('G')), sum)

# apply both functions to the input
aggregations = toolz.juxt(pts_counter, g_counter)

# for each group's value compute aggregations 
toolz.valmap(aggregations, groups)
```

The output:

```
{('CHI', 'NBA', 'SG'): (18.3, 60.0),
 ('CLE', 'NBA', 'SG'): (11.2, 46.0),
 ('MIA', 'NBA', 'PG'): (16.2, 61.0),
 ('MIA', 'NBA', 'SG'): (315.4, 887.0)}
```

Comment: thanks. This is an interesting solution but I am getting an error on compose_left ```AttributeError: module 'toolz' has no attribute 'compose_left'```. I tried compose which doesn't throw an error but when I run ```toolz.valmap(aggregations, groups)``` I get ```TypeError: 'float' object is not callable```. I will keep at it and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Maybe you are using an old version of `toolz` because in `0.10.0` it is there  https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz/blob/master/toolz/functoolz.py#L592

Comment: Apologies, I have been offline the last couple of days. I updated the toolz package and it worked! I will add an accept to your answer. Thanks.